# Error when installing entropy module

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to install entropy module with PyCharm and I'm getting this error :
"**error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181**"

I've tried with pip also, but still can't install this module. 
Can anybody help me with that ?

Setup : Windows 10, python 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try download package and patch setup.py :

```
libraries=['m'] => libraries=['msvcrt']
```